# How to check if .so file is ready to be used ? -newbie

Tags: software-installation

I have a .so file, which when executed with ldd gives this output.

```
$ldd _file.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd04795000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff1d2f2f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff1d2d2b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff1d2b0c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff1d2783000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff1d23e5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff1d21cd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff1d1ddc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff1d34e7000)
```

Does this mean that _file.so is ready & can be used  by other programs?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ready & can be used"? Is this just a philosophical question - or is there an actual issue you are trying to solve (such as a program or application failing to start/run)?

Comment: @steeldriver by ready to use i mean can the _file.so be interfaced & used in into other programs ?